# Fiddler investigation of RPC (extjs client-library)

Tags: ajax, extjs, fiddler

I captured a log at a clients site using:

> Fiddler (v2.2.9.1) Session Archive.
>   See http://www.fiddler2.com

and have some requests that seem wierd to me:

```
Request Count:  1
Bytes Sent:  1,525
Bytes Received: 804

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected: 15:40:54:6546
ClientDoneRequest: 15:41:00:1390
Gateway Determination: 0ms
DNS Lookup:   0ms
TCP/IP Connect:  0ms
ServerConnected: 15:37:55:4202
ServerGotRequest: 15:41:00:1390
ServerBeginResponse: 15:41:01:7171
ServerDoneResponse: 15:41:01:7171
ClientBeginResponse: 15:41:01:7171
ClientDoneResponse: 15:41:01:7171

 Overall Elapsed: 00:00:07.0625000
```

What is the deal with the clientconnected and clientdonerequest timestamps?  I have seen previous entries saying that the clietn connected timestamp is not reflective of the current request in older versions of fiddler, but this version used is subsequent to the bug fixes.

What is a reasonable explanation of this delay in sending?  Is this a fiddler issue - or is there something in my code I need to be investigating?  I definitely noticed a latency on their end when using the app (seems to be backed up by fiddler); they have ie 7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you ended up with this result-- The ClientBeginRequest timer was added to Fiddler v2.2.8.7 to reflect when the client started sending the request to Fiddler, but I don't see it in your snippet above. Are *you* using 2.2.9 on your machine?

If the SAZ file is small, you can send it to me (Help > Send Feedback) and I'll have a look.

The ClientConnected timer can be confusing because Fiddler uses keep-alive sockets to the client, so the client may have made the connection to Fiddler a while ago, reused it a bunch of times, and hence the ClientConnected time may be much earlier than the ClientBeginRequest time.

Comment: i don't think I have 2.2.9 on my machine.  Will check once I hit the office